# Azure Luis Bot handle an intent where the entity can be a number or a word?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-language-understanding

I am building a LUIS bot where the user can ask for information about a retail store. The user may reference the store by store number (e.g. 700, 350) and I have this working OK. But users could also refer to the store by store name, e.g. MyStore Tokyo or MyStore New York. How can I simply handle this scenario? Do I need to build two separate intents (with the same utterances virtually?) Or is there a better way?

Comment: add the store numbers and name into an entity list and then use that entity reference in your utterance

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that the store numbers and store names are stored in a CosmosDB. So at present, my intent utterances use the store number 400 as an example, and the intent then drives a query to the database to find the manager for that store. But the person could also reference the store name? I could do something hacky to work out if the entity is a number or a string, and if string, look up using a different SQL query..but that seems clunky?

Comment: You are looking for "any solution" - you don't need to base it on LUIS model, right?  You would prefer to get "store" from your DB independently before or after the LUIS is invoked and use store related data in the answer, correct?

Comment: I guess... I just assumed LUIS was the right way to go.... I did think of another solution, which was to use LUIS to pick out the entity of store (whether it's a number or a name) then test whether the entity can be parsed as an int.. if it can, it must be a store number, if it can't, it must be a store name, and then shape the query to CosmosDB accordingly. That just seemed hacky? If you have a better idea i"m all ears :) I just want the user to be able to ask the question using either store name or number and get the same response back

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the store as an entity, this is exactly what list entities are used for, which you can read about how to implement in the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-quickstart-intent-and-list-entity).

For example if I wanted to refer to an employee, I could refer to that employee in my utterance by name, employeeId, email, etc. using the list entity.

In your case you would create a store list entity and have synonym values of number and name.